# Removing first n characters from folder names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm fairly new to batch, my problem is the following:

I have a long list of folders and need to delete the first 3 characters from each of their names. Think 01_Folder1, 02_Folder2, 03_Folder3 and so on. I've tried patching together pieces of CMD commands I've found on the web but could not come up with a script that does what I want it to do. I've even tried using VBScript as I'm more familiar with VB in general but failed to find a solution as well.

Is there an easy way to solve this?

Edit:
Here's my attempt; it's giving me a syntax error but as I am not versed enough in CMD, I cannot really see why:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
for /d %%i in ("%~dp0*") do (set name=%%i && ren "!name!" "!name:~3!")
endlocal
```

Comment: two issues: you add an unwanted space to the variable. Use `set "name=%%i"` to avoid this. Second: your code returns a full qualified filename (`C:\path\to\xx_Folder1`). The three chars you remove are "C:\". See `for /?`, especially the "modifiers" section, then use `... set "name=%%~ni" & ren "%%i" "!name:~3!%%~xi"` (or use @Mofi's suggestion, which is more safe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **FOR** command line does not work because of assigned to loop variable `i` is the name of a directory with full path and so removing the first three characters results in removing drive letter, colon and backslash from path of the directory and not the first three characters from directory name. Further the full qualified directory name is assigned with an additional space to environment variable `name` because of the space between `%%i` and operator `&&`.

One solution would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 
for /d %%i in ("%~dp0*") do set "name=%%~nxi" && ren "%%i" "!name:~3!"
endlocal
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that directory names with one or more exclamation marks in name or path are not processed correct because of enabled [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) resulting in interpreting `!` in full directory name as begin/end of a delayed expanded environment variable reference.

Another solution is quite simple with using just the command line:

```
@for /D %%i in ("%~dp0*_*") do for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%j in ("%%~nxi") do @ren "%%i" "%%k"
```

The outer **FOR** searches in directory of the batch file for non-hidden subdirectories matching the pattern `*_*`.

For each directory name assigned with full path to loop variable `i` one more **FOR** command is used which processes just the string after last backlash (directory name without path) and splits the string up into substrings (tokens).

The string delimiter is an underscore as defined with option `delims=_`. The option `tokens=1*` tells **FOR** to assign first underscore delimited string to specified loop variable `j` and everything after one or more underscores after first underscore delimited string to next but one loop variable `k` according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

The inner **FOR** would ignore a directory name on which first substring starts with a semicolon as being the default end of line character. But in this case no directory has `;` at beginning of its name.

There is one problem remaining with this command line. It does not work on drives with FAT32 or exFAT as file system, just by chance on drives with NTFS file system. The reason is that the list of non-hidden directories changes in file system while the outer **FOR** iterates over the directory entries matching the pattern.

A better solution loads first the list of directories to rename into memory of Windows command process which is processing the batch file before starting with renaming the directories.

```
@for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir "%~dp0*_*" /AD-H /B 2^>nul') do for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%j in ("%%i") do @ren "%~dp0%%i" "%%k"
```

**FOR** executes in this case in background one more command process with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments. So executed in background is with Windows installed to `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "C:\Batch\File\Path\*_*" /AD-H /B 2>nul
```

**DIR** searches in directory of the batch file for

- non-hidden directories because of option `/AD-H` (attribute directory and not hidden)
- matching the wildcard pattern `*_*`
- and outputs just the directory names in bare format because of option `/B` without path to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) of background command process.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** respectively the Windows command process processing the batch file captures everything written to standard output handle of background command process and starts processing it as described above after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself. So there is in memory already a list of directory names and so the executed **REN** command does not result anymore in a changed list of directory names on processing one after the other.

Please note that a directory with name `01__Underscore_at_beginning` is renamed to `Underscore_at_beginning` and not to `_Underscore_at_beginning` by both single line solutions.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Wow, fantastic answer, thank you very much! I'll definitely read this more than once!